# Visual c# Program reading wrong Settings (PDB) file

Tags: c#

Ok I have created a program which saves text into settings file. So at end I have Program.exe file and Program.PDB file in my debug folder along with other files.
Then I use installshield which uses those 2 files to create Single Executable.

The thing is that when I installed the application from .exe file which I got from installshield, it worked flawless and I managed to save text and etc.
After I uninstalled the application from Add/Remove Programs.
I installed it again, and when I launched it, it showed me text that I saved before, not text from the fresh installed program/s PDB file.
I even tried to clean registry with ccleaner after uninstall.

Seems like it somehow saves and uses info from removed PDB file or something.
I save it using:
Properties.Settings.Default.text1 = textBox2.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

and load it using:
textBox2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.text1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDB file holds debug information. No need to distribute it.

The Application-scope settings are stored in  `application.exe.config`

The user-scoped settings are stored in a `user.config` somewhere under each users profile folder, not so easy to remove them all maybe. But make sure you bump the version number on each release and you will have a clean slate.

Comment: Didn't help. Tried to make exe from all files from debug folder, and bumped version up, but he still ignores the setting files in his folder and reads them from somewhere unknown. Shows the one I saved the 1st time.

Comment: OK, 2 questions: a) is it a User-Setting and b) do you want it per user?

Comment: No. I just configured it in Project properties settings, and used it in form. I would want it per user but I don't know that much about settings.

Comment: Project properties shows a User/Application dropdown. What does it say?

Comment: It says Application,Build,Build Events,Debug,Resources,Settings,Reference Paths,Signing,Security,Publish. I used Settings to store textBox.Text in it, and load from it.

Comment: Look at the Settings tab closely.

Comment: I can see the things I put in there: name: text1, type: string, scope:user, value: This is my stored text.

Comment: I checked now and when I use Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); it saves them to C:\Users\AppData thats why he doesn't remove them when I uninstall it or remove it. Dunno if there is a way to store settings file in the same directory as program.

Comment: Maybe. Anyway, you helped me. I would never look that far into projects and different folders without your support so. Ty. You helped me.